# UIScrollView (horizontal) not working on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ios8, uiscrollview, ios7.1, ios8.3

I have an iOS app (objectiv C) running on both iOS 7 and iOS 8. On iOS 7 (only) though, I have the following issue:
One component which is a subclass of UIScrollView (with horizontal scroll) does not scroll.
Browsing the net I’ve read about similar problems, but when I tried, nothing worked.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Since it works fine on iOS 8. I do not have any specific (buggy) code to show, but I must be missing some detail critical for iOS 7.

Comment: how are you setting your scrollView.contentSize?

Comment: Like this:     scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(myArray.count*46.0, tlbxHeight);
And I checked that the values make sense.